# S1166 exception handler shouild preserve original exception generates false positive

Tags: sonarqube

On SonarQube 7.9.1, the snippet bellow throws an squid:1166 violation. When I look at the code it seems to me that this exception is handled correctly. What is wrong?

```
} catch (final Exception ex) {
  Valeur[index] = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i highly urge you to take a closer look at the [issue description](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1166):

> When handling a caught exception, the original exception's message and stack trace should be logged or passed forward.

This means you should at least log your exception, with some kind of information, as this might be crucial on a later step. Also see the additional references at the bottom, which also provide neat information.

The easiest way would be to [log](https://www.baeldung.com/java-logging-intro) this message just on debug level like

```
} catch (final Exception ex) {
    log.debug("an exception occurred, oh no!", ex);
    Valeur[index] = "";
}
```

or if you do think, this is not needed at all, you always have the possibility to mark issues as false positives, or add a comment on the same line starting with `// NOSONAR` so issues on the same line will be ignored, which is something i would not recommend. like

```
} catch (final Exception ex) { // NOSONAR i do not want to log this
    Valeur[index] = "";
}
```